# How to retrieve all entries with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

There is my problem :

```
enter code here
```

I have a table called test that looks like this

```
id|  service  |   sub service  | Qt  |   date

1 | service_1 | sub_service_11 |  3  | 2011-12-03
2 | service_1 | sub_service_12 |  6  | 2011-12-03
3 | service_1 | sub_service_13 |  4  | 2011-12-03
```

Later I have a table called datedim that looks like this

```
id|   date 

1 | 2011-12-01
2 | 2011-12-02
3 | 2011-12-03
4 | 2011-12-04
5 | 2011-12-05
```

What I am trying to do is that for each sub_service bring back all the date from datedim even if there is no match.

So basically something that would look like this

```
sub_service_11 | 2011-12-01 | NULL
sub_service_11 | 2011-12-02 | NULL
sub_service_11 | 2011-12-03 | 3
sub_service_11 | 2011-12-04 | NULL
sub_service_11 | 2011-12-05 | NULL
sub_service_12 | 2011-12-01 | NULL
sub_service_12 | 2011-12-02 | NULL
sub_service_12 | 2011-12-03 | 6
sub_service_12 | 2011-12-04 | NULL
sub_service_12 | 2011-12-05 | NULL
sub_service_13 | 2011-12-01 | NULL
sub_service_13 | 2011-12-02 | NULL
sub_service_13 | 2011-12-03 | 4
sub_service_13 | 2011-12-04 | NULL
sub_service_13 | 2011-12-05 | NULL
```

I did try RIGHT JOIN, UNIONS and stuff but I can't figure it out.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish that ?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a table that lists every possible sub_service or do you just have 'DISTINCT sub_service FROM test'?

Comment: I do have a table containing a sub_service list. I did not think of it put I can join it two times, on sub_service and on datedim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
select 
  ss.sub_service, 
  dd.date,
  ts.qt
from 
  (datedim dd, (select distinct sub_service from test) ss)
 left join test ts on (dd.date = ts.date and ts.sub_service = ss.sub_service)
order by ss.sub_service, dd.date
```

Comment: As soon as you add another date into test (e.g. sub_service_11, 2011-12-04) this will produce duplicate dates for that sub_service.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks very much I would have never found this solution. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a table containing each sub_service (lets call it sub_service_list) you should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT
s.sub_service, d.date, t.Qt
FROM (sub_service_list s,datedim d) 
LEFT JOIN test t ON s.sub_service=t.sub_service AND d.date=t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
select t.id, sub_service, case when d.date = t.date then qt else null end as qt
from test t cross join datedim d 
order by sub_service, d.date
```

Comment: > In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
And that will not solve OPs issue

Comment: It's right Adrian... you test the query anyway? Only to know if work

Comment: Yes, I did. The output is NOT what OP wants